# React typescript how use types useState and render list in tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I set type to `useState` and render list with map in React TypeScript?

I have a component:

```
export type Item = {
  name: string;
  title: string;
};
export type ItemTypes = {
  item: Item[];
};

export const ItemList: FC = () => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState<ItemsTypes | []>([])

   useEffect(() => {
    let items = [
      {
        name: "A",
        title: "B",
      },
      {
        name: "C",
        title: "D",
      }
    ]
    setItems()
   }, [);

   return (
     <div>
         {items?.map((item) => (
          <>{item.name}</>
         ))}
     </div>
   )
}
```

And under **.map** line red stroke and saying:

```
any
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'ItemTypes | []'.
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined `ItemTypes` is not an array but instead an object having property item, hence the error. Use `Item[]` instead.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([])
```

Comment: yes it's worked but useState<Item[]>(null) here need to be useState<Item[]>([])

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with the your implementation.

First if you want to `export` the type alias `ItemTypes` you can set the type alias for `ItemTypes` like this `export type ItemTypes = Item[]`.

Second, you are never calling `setItems` with the `items` you have created in `useEffect`.

Lastly, because you are trying to access the `name` property on each item you should be checking `item.length` in a conditional otherwise it will throw an error `cannot access property name of undefined` if you do try to load the items asynchronously.

Solution

```
    export type Item = {
      name: string;
      title: string;
    };

    export type ItemTypes = Item[];

    export const ItemList: FC = () => {
       const [items, setItems] = useState<ItemsTypes | []>([])

       useEffect(() => {
        let items = [
          {
            name: "A",
            title: "B",
          },
          {
            name: "C",
            title: "D",
          }
        ]
        setItems(items)
       }, []);

       return (
         <div>
             {
               items.length && items.map((item) => (<p>{item.name}</p>) )

             }
         </div>
       )
    }
```